# Renaming a computer Invalid Method Parameters C#

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, wmi, rename

Why does this work:

```
using System;
using System.Management;

public class InvokeMethod
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ManagementClass processClass = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process");
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = processClass.GetMethodParameters("Create");
        inParams["CommandLine"] = "calc.exe";
        InvokeMethodOptions methodOptions = new InvokeMethodOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue);
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = processClass.InvokeMethod("Create", inParams, methodOptions);
    }
}
```

And this NOT work:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ManagementClass rename = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = rename.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
        inParams.SetPropertyValue("Name", "Name1234");
        InvokeMethodOptions methodOptions = new InvokeMethodOptions(null, System.TimeSpan.MaxValue);
        ManagementBaseObject outParams = rename.InvokeMethod("Rename", inParams, methodOptions);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

The problem here is this line:

```
ManagementBaseObject outParams = rename.InvokeMethod("Rename", inParams, methodOptions);
```

Invalid Method Parameters.
I understand you have to run it as administrator as is for it to do anything but I just want it to work.

Comment: you do not need to set a username and password they default to null and since the computer will always be in a work group don't worry about domain issues either.

Comment: This looks related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112968/how-can-i-use-invoke-wmimethod-to-rename-a-computer

Comment: And this link answers your question more directly: http://www.developmentnow.com/g/33_2005_8_0_0_574655/Problems-with-Rename-Method-of-Win32-Computer-System.htm

Comment: @MattSmith i tried this:
    string oldName = System.Environment.MachineName;
    ManagementClass rename = new ManagementClass("Win32_Computersystem.Name ='" + oldName + "'"); came up with invalid Parameter on that second line.

Comment: The link shows creation of a ManagementObject, not a ManagementClass

Comment: Either way, http://pastebin.com/Xiz5fvqL that guy was right and it works.